# Whenever I try to open my .pyw file with pythonw.exe I receive the error "File cannot by access by the system"

Tags: python, file, permissions

I have a .pyw (pythonw) file that works perfectly when ran through cmd. However, I am tryin to have it run 'normally' through file explorer. For that, I have to open it with pythonw. However, when I select pythonw to open it with, I receive an error. This is a system pop-up that does not let me continue with opening the file.

Here is how I get to that error:

```
-Right click .pyw (pythonw) file
-Open with...
-Choose an app on your PC
-I select the file "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pythonw.exe"
-I receive the pop-up "The file cannot be accessed by the system"
```

[The pop-up I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfYWS.png)

Comment: Is this the complete error message? How is it shown: In a GUI message box, terminal/console or somehow else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sorry I made have made the information more clear as of now in the original post. It is a seemingly system pop up, with the first line reading, "pythonw.exe" and second line reading, "The file cannot be accessed by the system"